# Changing section background based on time

Tags: javascript, html, css

The first section of my website contains a picture. I want the picture to change based on the local time. For example between 6 AM until 6 PM the "day picture" will be shown, and the rest of the time the "night picture" will be shown. I have two classes in my CSS file one called Day the other Night:

```
    .day {
           background-image: url("./css/images/daymode.jpg");
           background-size: cover;
}
.night {
         background-image: url("./css/images/nightmode.jpg");
         background-size: cover;
}
```

this is the HTML section I would like to change its the background:

```
    <section class="home-section section-hero overlay slanted" id="home-section">
```

that's my JavaScript file:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getHours();
  if (n > 18 || n < 6)
    // If time is after 7PM or before 6AM, apply night theme to ‘body’
    document.body.className = "night";
  if (n > 6 && n < 18) document.body.className = "day";
});
```

I can't figure out how to put these day and night classes in the same class of the section element so it will recognize them and I can control it with the js file.

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but if you want to target only changing the background on your section, then you need to change the CSS selectors slightly.  While you CAN have both a 'day' and 'night' class, it is easier to just have a default, and then an overridden 'night' theme.

Since you are already using `$(document).ready`, I'll assume you have jQuery included, so I've modified your function to take advantage of this and preserving whatever additional classes may have already been present on the body.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('night',IsNight());
  setInterval(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('night',IsNight());
  },60000);
});

function IsNight()
{
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getHours();
  return (n >= 18 || n < 6);
}
```

```css
#home-section {
  background-image: url("./css/images/daymode.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.night #home-section {
  background-image: url("./css/images/nightmode.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="home-section section-hero overlay slanted" id="home-section">blah</section>
```

Here is the same thing, slightly modified so that you don't have to wait for day/night.  This changes every second instead and uses color instead of background-iamge.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('night');  
  },1000);
});
```

```css
#home-section {
  background-image: url("./css/images/daymode.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  color: yellow;
}

.night #home-section {
  background-image: url("./css/images/nightmode.jpg");
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="home-section section-hero overlay slanted" id="home-section">blah</section>
```

Comment: Your solution works! Thank a lot just thought about the fact that it'll only change when it's one hour after what I set. Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, your javascript code is a bit off, but if you change the night detection to `if (n >= 18 || n < 6)` then you will get what you described, where after 6pm it is night.

Comment: I'm playing with the time of my system, and it doesn't seem to change it immediately. Using the SetInterval it just changing the pictures rapidly every second. so I deleted it and used the first method you used and yeah it doesn't switch any other second but it not changing immediately according to the system's clock.

Comment: Correct, it only sets the class when the document first loads. If you want it to change the theme if a user is still on that page, then you will need to periodically run your javascript.

Comment: I updated the answer so that it will update the theme without needing to refresh the page.  I have it check the time every 60 seconds (60000 milliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if{..}else{..}`

for you understanding i have set the time of day you can comment it and set it to current time

```js
var d = new Date('Thu Feb 20 2020 07:35:09 GMT+0530 ');

//var d = new Date();

var n = d.getHours();

if (n > 18 || n < 6) {
  // If time is after 7PM or before 6AM, apply night theme to ‘body’
  document.body.className = "night";
} else {
  document.body.className = "day";
}
```

```css
.day {
  background-image: url("./css/images/daymode.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: orange;
}

.night {
  background-image: url("./css/images/nightmode.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an ID on your section element, you can more easily do:

```
var section = document.getElementById('home-section');
var period;
// your logic to define whether it's day or night, and it's set to 'period'

// then, remove previous set classes
section.classList.remove('day');
section.classList.remove('night');

// finally, set the recently defined period
section.classList.add(period);
```

This way, since both of your `day` and `night` classes share the `background-size: cover` property, you can move it into your styles for the `#home-section` css rules.